# Flask configuration paths

Tags: python, flask, debian

So I have this code in my init:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('app.cfg')
```

My folder structure goes like this:

```
/config.py 
/app.cfg
/app/__init__.py
```

However, this code seems to find my config.py in the root, but it's searching inside my app folder for my app.cfg. How do I make it look for my configuration file in the correct place, without having to put it in my app folder.

Should I be using `from object` and rename my app.cfg to app.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official docs (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Config):

> from_pyfile(filename, silent=False)
>
> > > Updates the values in the config from   a Python file. This function behaves as if the file was imported as module with thefrom_object() function.
> > >
> > > Parameters: filename – the filename of the config. This can either be an absolute filename or a filename relative to the root path.silent – set to True if you want silent failure for missing files.

So, if you don't want to put your cfg file in your app folder one of the things you can do is to set relative route to root folder (that seems to be "./app" directory) in your "from_pyfile" call.

```
from_pyfile('../app.cfg')
```

should work..